# How to get the original exception when using ContinueWith()?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0, task

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var tasks = new Task[1];

            tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => throwExceptionAfterOneSecond())
                .ContinueWith(task => {
                    Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith()"); }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }

            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception received: " + ex.InnerExceptions.Single().Message);
            }
        }

        static void throwExceptionAfterOneSecond()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

`Exception received: A task was canceled.`

My question is simple: How do I get at the original `InvalidOperationException("TEST");` rather than a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException`?

Note that if you remove the `.ContinueWith()` part, this works as I expected and the output in that case is `Exception received: TEST`.

(Also note that this example is using .Net 4.5, but the original code must use .Net 4.0)

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the answers, this is now working. I chose the following solution - I needed to wait on both the original task AND the continuation task:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var tasks = new Task[2];

            tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => throwExceptionAfterOneSecond());

            tasks[1] = tasks[0].ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                    Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith()"); });
            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }

            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception received: " + ex.InnerExceptions.Single().Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }

        static void throwExceptionAfterOneSecond()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about removing `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted`?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy If you do that, you don't get any exception at all from `Task.WaitAll()`.

Comment: You're awaiting the continuation task, rather than the inner task. Add the continuation later: `tasks[0].ContinueWith(...)`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert How would I wait for the continuation to complete in that case? Perhaps I could put both into the array of Task[]?

Comment: In .NET 4.5 I'd call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the antecedent task inside the continuation (which ultimately falls through to `TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess`), but with .NET 4.0 you have to do the extra work yourself, by getting your continuation to pull apart the `AggregateException` thrown in the antecedent task and rethrow.

Comment: The rethrowing idea is an anti-pattern as noted under the corresponding answer. It's also less clean. If you really want that a better way to do it is `task.Wait()` which will throw for you. It creates a new wrapper exception.

Comment: @usr The trouble with `Task.Wait()` is that I have several tasks to wait for. My real code is in fact only checking for one particular kind of custom exception (`InvalidCrcException`), and is only throwing if that's the kind of exception. I omitted all that from my question for brevity.

Comment: @usr I've therefore decided to just use the first solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store a reference to `Task.Run(() => throwExceptionAfterOneSecond())` so that you can later examine it's `Exception` property. This is the only task that faulted. Examining any other task will not provide that exception.

I'd also not rely on `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted` because this pretty much forces using exceptions for control flow. It is hard to wait for a non-normally completed task without an exception being thrown.

```
.ContinueWith(task => {
     if (task.Status == RanToCompletion) Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith()");
}
```

Comment: This approach works, I'll add the final solution to my question.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to catch the exception in the `catch` statement you could rethrow from inside the continue. E.g.

```
tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => throwExceptionAfterOneSecond())
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Throw the inner exception
            throw task.Exception.InnerException;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith()");
    });
```

Comment: This is the common rethrowing anti pattern. Loses stack information and also doesn't work in case of multiple exceptions.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit 'quick and dirty' but if all that was required was to catch the original `InvalidOperationException` rather than `TaskCanceledException` then it allows it. Additional logic could be used to check for multiple exceptions or wrap as inner exception to preserve stack trace in innerException etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could split up the `ContinueWith` part in to such a way that they are separate in case of exception and separate in case of sucess. here's an example:

```
var tasks = new Task[1];
tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => throwExceptionAfterOneSecond());

// For error handling.
tasks[0].ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // Your logic to handle the exception goes here

        // Aggregate exception
        Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.Message);

        // Inner exception, which is your custom exception
        Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

// If it succeeded.
tasks[0].ContinueWith(task => 
{
    // success
    Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith()");
},TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```